# The bullet from the data provider is not showing

Tags: javascript, graph, charts, amcharts, stock

I am using AmCharts 3 and experiencing a problem with my chart. The bullet stops showing up when I zoom out on the stock graph named 'medication'.
graph image in zoom out (https://i.stack.imgur.com/btdWu.png)
graph image in zoom in (https://i.stack.imgur.com/0lXbo.png)

I tried all the properties of amchart3 to shown the bullet like: "hideBulletsCount: 0" but nothing happen, I want the bullet to change based on the data provider, but it is not visible when the period selector is set to more than one day. I would like the bullet to always be shown

```
 var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
    type: "stock",

    dataSets: [{
        dataProvider: chartDataLive,
        fieldMappings: [
            {
                fromField: "SSY",
                toField: "SSY"
            },
            {
                fromField: "SZY",
                toField: "SZY"
            },
            {
                fromField: "PJY",
                toField: "PJY"
            },
            {
                fromField: "Codeine/guailFENesin",
                toField: "Codeine/guailFENesin"
            },
            {
                fromField: "Azelastine",
                toField: "Azelastine"
            },
            {
                fromField: "Clarinex",
                toField: "Clarinex"
            },
            {
                fromField: "Diovan HTC",
                toField: "Diovan HTC"
            },
            {
                fromField: "Gabapentin",
                toField: "Gabapentin"
            },
            {
                fromField: "LEVOFLOXACIN",
                toField: "LEVOFLOXACIN"
            },
            {
                fromField: "Naproxen",
                toField: "Naproxen"
            },
            {
                fromField: "Pramipexole",
                toField: "Pramipexole"
            },
            {
                fromField: "Repatha",
                toField: "Repatha"
            },
            {
                fromField: "PRAVACHOL",
                toField: "PRAVACHOL"
            },
            {
                fromField: "Welco",
                toField: "Welco"
            },
            {
                fromField: "Amlodipine",
                toField: "Amlodipine"
            }
        ],
        categoryField: "DATE",
        stockEvents: (function(){
            var guideArray = []
            guideArray.push({
                date: new Date("2018-08-12T16:00:00.000Z"),
                type: "arrowUp",
                backgroundColor: "#85CDE6",
                graph: "m3",
                description: "This is description of an event"
        
            })
            return guideArray
        }()),
       
        
    }],
    

    panels: [
        {
            showCategoryAxis: false,
        title: "Blood Pressure",
        percentHeight: 60,
        parseDates: true,

            legend: {},

            stockGraphs: (function(){
                var guideArray = []
            
                guideArray.push(
                    {
                        hideBulletsCount: 0,
                        id: "graph1",
                        valueField: "SSY",
                        type: "line",
                        title: "Systolic",
                        bullet:"round",
                        // hideBulletsCount: 0,
                        fillAlphas: 0,
                        lineColor: lineColors[0],
                        fillColors: lineColors[0],
                        useDataSetColors: false,
                        balloonText: "[[title]]<br><b><span style='font-size:14px;'>[[SSY]]</span></b>"
                    }
                )
                guideArray.push(
                    {
                        id: "graph2",
                        valueField: "SZY",
                        type: "line",
                        title: "Diastolic",
                        bullet:"round",
                        fillAlphas: 0,
                        lineColor: lineColors[1],
                        fillColors: lineColors[1],
                        useDataSetColors: false,
                        balloonText: "[[title]]<br><b><span style='font-size:14px;'>[[SZY]]</span></b>"
                    }
                )
                guideArray.push(
                    {
                        id: "graph3",
                        valueField: "PJY",
                        type: "line",
                        title: "Mean Arterial Pressure (MAP)",
                        bullet:"round",
                        fillAlphas: 0,
                        lineColor: lineColors[2],
                        fillColors: lineColors[2],
                        useDataSetColors: false,
                        balloonText: "[[title]]<br><b><span style='font-size:14px;'>[[PJY]]</span></b>"
                    }
                )
                return guideArray
            }())
        },
        {
            title: "Medication",
            percentHeight: 40,
            bulletSize: 20,
            showBalloon : true,
         
            stockGraphs: (function(){
                var guideArray = []
                for (var i = 0; i < medication.length; i++) {
                    guideArray.push(
                        {
                            id:"m"+[i],
                            valueField: medication[i].category,
                            type: "line",
                            cornerRadiusTop: 2,
                            fillAlphas: 0,
                            bulletField:"bullet",
                            bulletBorderColor: "black",
                            bulletBorderAlpha: 1,
                            bulletBorderThickness: 3,
                            bulletSize: 1,
                            showBalloon : true,
                            hideBulletsCount: 0,
                            lineThickness: 3,
                            lineColor: medColors[i],
                            fillColors: medColors[i],
                            useDataSetColors: false,
                            balloonText: medication[i].category,

                       
                        }
                        
                    )
                }
                return guideArray
            }()),
            stockLegend: {
                valueTextRegular: " ",
                markerType: "none"
            }
    },

    ],

    panelsSettings: {
        startDuration: 1,
        usePrefixes: true
    },

    categoryAxesSettings: {
        dashLength: 5,
        minPeriod : "hh",
        equalSpacing: true
    },

    valueAxesSettings: {
        dashLength: 5
    },

    chartScrollbarSettings: {
        graph: "graph1",
        graphType: "line"
    },

    chartCursorSettings: {
        valueBalloonsEnabled: true
    },

    periodSelector: {
        periods: [{
            period: "DD",
            count: 1,
            label: "1 day"
        }, {
            period: "DD",
            selected: true,
            count: 5,
            label: "5 days"
        }, {
            period: "MM",
            count: 1,
            label: "1 month"
        }, {
            period: "YYYY",
            count: 1,
            label: "1 year"
        }, {
            period: "YTD",
            label: "YTD"
        }, {
            period: "MAX",
            label: "MAX"
        }]
    }
});
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/chocojam27/jorfm2yu/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Mystery of the Vanishing Bullets ... took me a while, but it's interesting. The cause is apparently [the data grouping function](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v3/tutorials/understanding-data-grouping-of-stock-chart/) of amcharts stock. It seems others [reported](https://github.com/amcharts/amcharts4/issues/1764) similar problems a while ago, with v4.

The immediate solution is to disable data grouping by adding

```js
chart.categoryAxesSettings.maxSeries = 0;
```

at the end of the script.

This creates a problem if all that data is shown, especially with full MAX interval which is useless and should probably be removed.

Now, that might be exactly what you want since data grouping is modifying the values of the blood pressure (not to mention mine and probably yours) which might not be OK. However, if you want data grouping only for the upper panel and no data grouping for the lower panel (to preserve the bullets on zoom), then there's no simple solution ... we may explore the next days some tricks like creating a second hidden x axis, since data grouping appears to be controlled per axes (hopefully), and not per series.

Comment: I also tried changing the bullet from bulletField: "bullet" to bullet: "round". The property hideBulletsCount: 0 works fine without using maxSeries. It's just strange that when I customize the bullet, it stops working. However, your answer solved my problem. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @RaffyReyes you may combine `bulletField: "bullet"` with `bullet:"round"`. I think what happens is this: it the point has a `bullet`, that bullet is used, if it has no bullet, `round` is used; when data grouping kicks in, at larger periods, it creates a new point from the coordinates of the points it groups (it may be just one point it "groups"); that new point has no bullet, so the default `round` is used. It would've been a nice feature if it also grouped bullets in a way, like taking the most used bullet of the group.